# How do I link to an external stylesheet in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I'm trying to link to the YUI reset stylesheet in my RoR layout using the following statement...

```
<%= stylesheet_path("http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.1/build/reset/reset-min.css") %>
```

but this path is being echoed on my page instead of being applied.  I got this syntax from the the rails docs.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `stylesheet_link_tag` as described in the [Rails API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/StylesheetTagHelpers.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag)

Comment: the link is not working. Its always better not to give external links if answer can be concise.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application','http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.1/build/reset/reset-min.css' %>
```